# Python String Comparisons, why does x for x not work with list of lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, for-loop

I am trying to get a value out of a list of array of strings based on another value in the same array.

```
zone = [x for x in zoneList if (x[2] == usageRow[2])][1]
```

This is not part of the code, just a sample of what the data looks like in a print
zoneList = [('BOB', 'HIGH_ZONE', 'WI'), ('MIKE', 'LOW_ZONE', 'IL'),....]
usageRow[2] = WI

The code above does not find the values, but this code does

```
for x in zoneList:
  if (x[2] == usageRow[2]):
     zone = x[1]
```

I don't understand why the comparison works in one but not the other.

I was expecting it to find the correct value

Thanks Brian61354270 for pointing out the missing [0]  This got me the results I needed
zone = [x for x in zoneList if (x[2] == usageRow[2])][0][1]

Comment: any reason you have an extraneous curly brace?

Comment: The first line should be `[ ... ][0][1]` instead of `[ ... ][1]`, no? In the top version, you're creating a list of tuples, and indexing `[1]` on that list. In the bottom, you're indexing `[1]` on a tuple entry.

Comment: Also you need quotes around "WI" in `usageRow[2] = WI`

Comment: @Brian61354270 yup. Index out of range otherwise.

Comment: the code you've posted *doesn't even compile*. Please **always** provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Brian61354270 , thanks for pointing that out, it was the missing [0]

Answer (score 0):

In your first line, you do `[x for x in zoneList if x[2] == usageRow[2]][1]`. However the list `[x for x in zoneList if x[2] == usageRow[2]]` will give you `[('BOB', 'HIGH_ZONE', 'WI')]` (tuple inside a list) which is not the same as `('BOB', 'HIGH_ZONE', 'WI')` (just a tuple).

What you need to do is first get the tuple from the list and the zone from the tuple. Try the following:

```py
zoneList = [('BOB', 'HIGH_ZONE', 'WI'), ('MIKE', 'LOW_ZONE', 'IL')]
usageRow = ["IL", "CA", "WI"]
zone = [x for x in zoneList if x[2] == usageRow[2]][0][1]
print(zone)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please be careful when writing code, as in your first code chunk there are a couple of syntax errors which make the code fail directly (maybe this is the reason it was failing).

Then, answering your question:

With the first line `zone = [x for x in zoneList if x[2] == 'WI'][1]` (note that I ommitted the unnecessary parentheses, and replaced the variable `usageRow[2]` by its value) you are using a list comprehension to create a list of tuples, and then selecting the `[1]` index from that list. If the input data you gave us is used, there will not be any tuple with index `[1]` in the resulting list (`zone`) and you will get a `IndexError: list index out of range`.
In that particular case, there will only be the tuple `('BOB', 'HIGH_ZONE', 'WI')` in the `[0]` index of the `zone` variable.

However, if you use a larger input, for example:

```
zoneList = [('BOB', 'HIGH_ZONE', 'WI'), ('MIKE', 'LOW_ZONE', 'IL'), ('SAM', 'LOW_ZONE', 'WI'), ('DAVID', 'LOW_ZONE', 'WI')]
```

you will see that now the code `zone = [x for x in zoneList if x[2] == 'WI'][1]` indeed returns a result which is `('SAM', 'LOW_ZONE', 'WI')`.

Summarizing, either you made a mistake while writing the first code chunk, or your input only had one `tuple` meeting the condition you specified in the list comprehension and then you get the `IndexError` back.

Hope it is clear enough.